# Passing std::string_view to API execting const std::string&

Tags: c++, std, c++17, stdstring

I am using Socket.IO library to create a client. While sending a message I have to pass my message (data) as  `sio::message::list(msg)`

```
void Socket_IO::send_message(std::string_view msg)      //Gives Error
//void Socket_IO::send_message(const std::string &msg)  //Works
{
    this->client.socket()->emit(Socket_IO::general_message, sio::message::list(msg), [&](sio::message::list const& msg) {
    });
}
```

class sio::message::list has a constructor

```
list(const string& text)
{
    m_vector.push_back(string_message::create(text));
}
```

but does not have a std::string_view constructor

Error :

```
'<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'std::string_view' to 'sio::message::list'
```

I wish to know is their any way I can pass std::string_view for API expecting const std::string&

I can't use c_str() function as the string might contain binary data which may contain null character (0x00).

I was thinking of creating a string object `sio::message::list(std::string str(msg))` but wish to inquire will it defeat the purpose of using std::string_view.

Comment: There is no purpose in using a string_view. string_view is designed for dealing with a range of immutable characters from some third-party string source. It's not a replacement for all strings in an api. Ideally it should have never been put in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with:

`this->client.socket()->emit(Socket_IO::general_message, sio::message::list(std::string(msg)), ...`

this makes the job done. It will initialize temporary string object and pass it to list constructor.

Comment: As mentioned in the last line of my post, I was wondering using std::string construction cause performance issues.

Comment: Every new object construction will, but unless you are developing for super-crutial time or memory restricted environment, it does not make difference and it solves your case.